# PHP upload image script isn't working

Tags: php, html, webforms, image-uploading

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    if(empty($_FILES['image'])) {
        echo "<p class=\"error\">Please upload an image...</p>\n";
    } else {
    $file_name= $_FILES['image']['name']; // original name
    $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; // temporary location on server
    $file_error = $_FILES['image']['error']; // reference to future error
    $file_ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if($file_ext != "jpeg" || "jpg" || "gif" || "png") {
        echo "<p class=\"error\">Please upload an image that has the extension .jpg/jpeg, .gif, or .png.</p>\n";
    } else {
        if($file_size > (10000000)) {
            echo "<p class=\"error\">Please upload an image that does not exceed the file size of 10MB.</p>\n";
        } else {
            if($file_error) {
                echo "<p class=\"error\">Sorry, an unexpected error occurred: ".$file_error."</p>\n";
            } else {
                $f_rename = "pfp/".time().".png";
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$f_rename);
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="upload_test_image.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've had trouble uploading any image as I cannot get past the file extension check. As I'm writing this, I'm also trying to dissect the problem on if it is exactly the extension verification that is the problem (could be that it just prints out the error statement I issued due to it being first if...else statement). Can anyone help find the problem within that or this code?

Comment: To troubleshoot, try outputting the value of `$file_ext` (and `$file_name` while you're at it).

Comment: It returns empty, so obviously it's not the extension error and if I just press the upload button within the form, it gives the same error, so problem is in actually uploading the image. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pathinfo() will need the path of your file not just filename.
To get extension you could try this:

```
$extension = preg_replace('@.+\.@', '', $_FILES['image']['name'])
```

Alternatively you can check $_FILES['image']['type'] as that might have the types you're looking for. finfo might be helpful too:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

Comment: It didn't solve an extension problem but it helped me realize that there's a problem in where the file is being uploaded. Still haven't solved it however, but I know that's the problem. Can you help?

Comment: It didn't solve an extension problem but it helped me realize that there's a problem in where the file is being uploaded. Still haven't solved it however, but I know that's the problem. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do boolean condition like this in PHP.

How about this, declare an array of allowed extensions:

```
$extensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "gif","png");
```

then check if the file extension is in the array:

```
if(!in_array($file_ext, $extensions)) {
    //Please upload an image that has the extension .jpg/jpeg, .gif, or .png.
}
```

Comment: It didn't solve an extension problem but it helped me realize that there's a problem in where the file is being uploaded. Still haven't solved it however, but I know that's the problem. Can you help?

Comment: Can you show me where you tested this? I might've solved the problem myself, but I'm open to hear how you tested this.

Comment: It works, turns out the pathinfo I used in my script was the one causing the disruption. Thanks for helping me however!